# SharePoint online (modern experience) : crawled metadata not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, 2019, managed-property, crawled-property

My company uses Sharepoint Online. I have a site on that SharePoint that uses the modern experience.

It's a "communication" site, if that changes anything. In the site content -> site pages (i.e. a SharePoint list) I added a column named "MyMetaDataColumn" and I want to use this column value as a filter in some web parts e.g. in the highlighted content web part.

As I understand, I therefore need to find the "crawled metadata" version of that column i.e. named "ows_MyMetaDataColumn" in the "search schema" of SharePoint to then map this to a managed property that I can then use to perform filtering.

I do not see this crawled metadata. I tried re-indexing the list. I tried re-indexing the site. No changes.

What am I missing? Which setting could prevent the column to be crawled and usable as I intend to ?

Comment: Do you have some data using the term? Has a full crawl been executed?

Comment: As suggested by @DerekGusoff, add some data in this new column for few site pages and try [manually re-indexing site pages library](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/crawl-site-content#reindex-a-document-library-or-a-list?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) again. Wait for 1-2 hours until crawl is completed properly. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: How can I know (I am not admin and don't have access to that) when it has been crawled?

Comment: And yes, I have pages using this column with different values

Answer (score 0):

For people facing the same issue.

In my case, the problem was the type of column. When I created the column I chose "choice" thinking it would be crawled anyway independently of the type given this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/automatically-created-managed-properties-in-sharepoint) providing the naming conventions for practically all types.

I changed the type of column to "metadata" and then it appears with the prefix ows_taxId.